# Out of space, even when I have around 300gb free

Tags: 14.04, partitioning, disk-usage

I have been using `Ubuntu 14.04` for a while now, but I still get confused sometimes by the directory structure. I have a 500gb harddisk (just the one partition) mounted on `/`.

I am running [TileStache (v1.50.1)](https://github.com/TileStache/TileStache) to cache [VectorTiles](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Vector_tiles), and I keep getting the error message that I am out of space. Even though I have around 290gb free. What is going on? How can I get my application to make use of the free space that I have (TileStache doesn't allow me to store the tiles it has created on a different partition)

This is the error I get: `OSError: [Errno 28] No space left on device: '/home/muzaffar/TileStache/scripts/~/cache2/stache/tmpXoywE3.json.gz`:

[image]

When I use `gparted` this is what I get: /dev/sda1 mountpoint / unused 300.21 GiB:

[image]

And inside the `scripts` folder referenced in the original error: Free space: 291.5 GB:

[image]

Comment: I think this could be a bug in TileStache.

Comment: I have TileStache running without any such issues on multiple other systems (running Windows 7 and RHEL 7.2 ), if it's a bug, it's specific to Ubuntu.

Comment: To reproduce it could be worth mentioning the version of TileStache you are using

Comment: TileStache v1.50.1 is the latest version and the one I'm using.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Error in your screenshot does not refer to the HDD space as you have rightfully pointed. It refers to the size of the "Device" in this case your tilestache cache.

Please check if there some junk files or old unused cache files. If so you can safely remove them and try again. In case you require further information, refer to the following thread.

http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2177876

Also check how much inodes you have left,

use `df -i` 
It should return something like

```
Filesystem      Inodes  IUsed   IFree IUse% Mounted on
udev            489954    491  489463    1% /dev
tmpfs           492649    483  492166    1% /run
/dev/sda5      3131408 246990 2884418    8% /
none            492649      2  492647    1% /sys/fs/cgroup
```

if there are sufficient inodes present there should be no reason why your cache cant grow. If this dint help either, please do revert with the output from the shell.

Comment: Filesystem       Inodes    IUsed   IFree IUse% Mounted on
udev            1007668      483 1007185    1% /dev
tmpfs           1010364      461 1009903    1% /run
/dev/sda1      30269440 30132261  137179  100% /

Comment: Apparently I am out of inodes, what can I do now?

Comment: @HasanMustafa if you're out of inodes you can only do one thing, tar up very old files, so they only use up one inode instead of multiple, cleaning out unneeded files, etc.. Every file is an inode, as well as each process running is one, since everything on Linux is a file.

Comment: @Videonauth I can't really do that since I need all the files that I am creating (The tiles that I am caching are mostly less than 1kb, so I end up with huge amount of very small files). Is there anything else i can do? from what I've read, I think my only option is to reformat a partition, increase the number of inodes and move my setup there.

Comment: @HasanMustafa This would as well work, or point your output really to a whole new partitions where nothing else is on it, then you should have in most cases an amount of inodes which should suffice except you're really creating a few million files.

Comment: I can't point the output to a new partition, TileStache doesn't allow me to.

Comment: gparted to split sda1, create a filesystem with bigger number of inodes, move  `stcache`  on this,  create a symlink  `stcache`  which point to new folder location

Comment: @HasanMustafa Before Trying to repartition, you can try and compress any folders that might have been in the same partition. A typical example might be */home/muzzaffar/Downloads*. 

Try and recompress/delete any archives (tar, gz, zip) you might have downloaded. Typically, any package you have downloaded and built from source or normal downloads also. This had helped me tremendously in the past.

After which you can use Gparted and create a new partition and use symklink to map it to your application cache.

Comment: I think I don't have any other viable option, I am dealing with a huge number of files here, even if I can compress folders in the same partition it won't be able to sustain my cache in the long run. I am dealing with millions of tiny files (most of which are less than 1Kb)

Comment: @HasanMustafa: if you can't change the output directory, use symlinks or `mount --bind` another partition over the expected/current directory. I don't see why this wouldn't work?

Comment: @knittl yeah that's what I meant, that the only viable options I have are to either reformat my whole drive or create a new partition with more inodes and use symlinks.